# C recursion problems

Tags: c, recursion

I have a query regarding a recursive function. This is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int);

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    int k=3;
    x = fun(k);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}

int fun(int a)
{
    int f;
    if(a == 1) return (1);
    f = 2 + fun(a-1);
    return (f);
}
```

where I have a value `K=3` in `STEP-6`. In `STEP-7` the function `fun(k)` pass the value of K to the called function in `STEP-11` `int fun(int a)`. In called function `fun(int a)` recursion occurred  2 times that is (3,2) making the value of `a=1`. Which is later in `STEP-14`, the value of `f` becomes 3, because f = 2 + (fun(1)=1). In `STEP-16` it get return to called function i.e `fun(int a)=3`. Which is supposed to print the value of `x is 3`, unlikely it is not. It is **x =5**

Comment: did (not) you miss the `2 + ..` part in case of the call with a value 3?

Comment: In the call `fun(3)`, there is two **subsequent recursive calls** with values 2 and 1...

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, i think so :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's check the calling sequence of `fun()`, shall we?

With an argument value of `3`, starting from `main()`

- `x = fun(3)`

  - `f = 2 + fun(2);`

    - `f = 2 + fun(1);`

Now, let's check the return values, just in the reverse order.

1. The last call, `fun(1)` returns `1`,
2. So the second call, `fun(2)`, returns `2 + 1` or `3`,
3. The last call, `fun(3)` returns `2 + 3` or `5`

and that is the call made from `main()`. So, in `main()`, `x` gets a value of `5`.

Answer (score 4):

The evalution of `fun(3)` looks like this:

```
fun(3)
2 + fun(3-1)
2 + fun(2)
2 + 2 + fun(2-1)
2 + 2 + fun(1)
2 + 2 + 1
5
```

From your description, I *think* you have some misconceptions about scopes in C (and recursion in general). The fact that `f` is assigned the value `3` inside `fun(2)` does *not* mean that the value of `f` in the scope of `fun(3)` changes - they are entirely separate variables.

Comment: Do i know , how does "2"  pop out in between 2 + 2 + fun(2-1) ?

Comment: Yes, `fun(2)` expands to `2 + fun(2-1)`. This is easier to see if we recognize that `f = ...; return f` is equivalent to `return ...`.

Answer (score 2):

For recursive functions, it is generally a good idea to draw a recursion tree to better visualise what is going on.

- f(3) will call f(2), f(2) will further call f(1), which is the base case.
- f(1) will return 1. Now f(2) will return 2 + 1 = 3.
- f(3) will now return 2 + 3 = 5.

Check out the recursion tree below:

```
     |------> returns (2 + 3) = 5
     |
    f(3)<---
     |     | 
     |     | returns (2 + 1)  = 3
    f(2)<---
     |     | returns 1
     |     |
    f(1)----
    (This is the base case. No further recursion. It returns 1).
```

Answer (score 1):

I see there's many good answer already posted. Still I'm posting this answer which maybe help you in future when you will deal some more complex recursion.

Whenever you find anything about recursion, try to solve it mathematically in your notebook first. A good approach is starting with the base case.

The function `fun(k)`'s base case is `fun(1)` which returns `1`. So start with the following:

```
fun(1) = 1 // let's read this, function fun(1) returns 1
```

Now for `fun(2)` what will gonna happen?

```
fun(2) = 2 + fun(1)
       = 2 + 1 // we already calculated fun(1) =1
       = 3
fun(3) = 2 + fun(2)
       = 2 + 3 // we already calculated fun(2) = 3
       = 5
```

I think now it makes sense why `x = 5`!